# rxjs/webSocket - WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, rxjs

I have initialized WebSocket on my backend.
Then use rxjs/webSocket to connect and receive the following error on the browser:

```
connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

server.js related code:

```js
const { app, onServerInitialized } = require('./app');

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT);
console.log('Server is running on port ' + process.env.PORT);
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
onServerInitialized(server);
```

app.js related code:

```js
const app = express();

const onServerInitialized = server => {
    const io = socketio(server);

    io.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log('subscrie');
    });
};

module.exports = { app, onServerInitialized };
```

WebSocketService

```js
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

export class WebSocketService {
    private ws$: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

    public getWSListener() {
        return this.ws$.asObservable().pipe();
    }

    public sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.ws$.next({ message });
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
constructor(
  private webSocketService: WebSocketService,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.webSocketService.getWSListener().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('event')
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `socket.io` package, and this package has server setted up at `/socket.io` path. So try this uri: `ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`

Also make sure that in `onServerInitialized` function you don't need to add this line at the bottom

```js
io.listen(+process.env.PORT);
```

**EDIT:**

Better use [`ngx-socket-io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io) package into Angular project

Comment: Then try this uri: `ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`, but I'm afraid you have to use `ngx-socket-io` package

Comment: Worked! Can you please explain why we need this params?

Comment: `EIO` is Engine.IO version, in this case version is `3` - latest, `transport` parameter is forcing protocol, because socket.io can work on `http` and `ws`